# Numpy - construct matrix from matrix of positions and values

Tags: python, numpy

I have a Nx3 matrix constructed as,

```
i   j  val
.   .   .
.   .   .
.   .   .
```

from which I want to construct a matrix where element x_ij = val. For example position-value matrix,

```
[[ 0 0 3 ] 
 [ 1 1 2 ] 
 [ 0 1 4 ]
 [ 1 0 1 ]
 [ 2 0 5 ]
 [ 2 1 2 ]]
```

would result in the matrix,

```
[[3 4]
 [1 2]
 [5 2]]
```

What is the most simple/succinct way to do this in numpy?

Comment: Seems like you could just do `x[:, -1].reshape(-1, x.shape[1] - 1)`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Make a blank array and fill it with the indexed values

```
In [541]: x = np.array([[0, 0, 3],
     ...:                      [1, 1, 2],
     ...:                      [0, 1, 4],
     ...:                      [1, 0, 1],
     ...:                      [2, 0, 5],
     ...:                      [2, 1, 2]])
     ...:                      
In [543]: arr = np.zeros((3,2),int)
In [544]: arr[x[:,0], x[:,1]] = x[:,2]
In [545]: arr
Out[545]: 
array([[3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [5, 2]])
```

In this case all elements of `arr` are defined, but this works even if some are left 0.  If there are duplicates, and you want to sum them, then the `coo` approach is convenient.  The `reshape` suggestions will have problems if `x` isn't complete.

Comment: Simple, readable and exactly what I needed. Thank you!

Comment: Follow-up question: Is there a similar way to construct a 3D-matrix if each coordinate corresponds to multiple values? @hpaulj

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to use a `coo_matrix`

```
>>> data = np.array([[0, 0, 3],
                     [1, 1, 2],
                     [0, 1, 4],
                     [1, 0, 1],
                     [2, 0, 5],
                     [2, 1, 2]])

>>> 
>>> from scipy import sparse
>>> i, j, v = data.T
>>> sparse.coo_matrix((v, (i, j)), (3, 2)).A
array([[3, 4],
       [1, 2],
       [5, 2]])
```

Note that this will create `0`s at missing positions, and if indices appear multiple times their values will be summed.

Comment: Thanks! I should've known to search for spare matrices. Is there any way to hinder multiple values being summed? I.e. if all coordinates correspond to multiple values, can a vector of all values at that coordinate be created?

Comment: @erikejan Not that I knew of. Also, such an array would have to be of object dtype which usually means you are losing most of the benefits of numpy arrays.

Answer (score 0):

This should get you what what you seek, with help of `coldspeed`'s solution:

```
x[np.lexsort(np.fliplr(x).T)][:, -1].reshape(-1, x.shape[1] - 1)
```

Comment: That's very fast but also quite obscure to me. Could you explain what it does?